# callback function undefined in ng-click function using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am having hard time calling callback function inside ng-click under ng-repeat.
Below is the snippet.

It is calling the ng-click function but when it is time to call the callback function - it fails - undefined - *cb is not a function* message

HTML part

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span ng-click="itemClick(cb)">{{item}}</span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
....
<script type="text/javascript">
  function cb(){
     alert('Hey');
  }
</script>
```

Angular

```
...
$scope.itemClick = function(cb) {
    cb();
};
```

I am new to angular.

Comment: wrong angular function, write this way $scope.itemClick = function(cb) {..........}, it may help

Comment: `itemClick(item)` is what you maybe want to achieve.

Comment: @JinnaBalu it is a typo error - i just type them, anyway it is in the correct format now, same with my code.

Comment: in itemClick function you are passing 'cb' as the variable, that is not used and you are trying to call cb() method.  In Html on ng-click=ItemClick(cb), how you got cb variable. can you post you complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when writing `<span ng-click="itemClick(cb)">{{item}}</span>` you expect `cb` to be a property on scope, but its not.

Its not very good practice to put functions global like this, like you're trying with `cb`. Why can't you just write whatever code you want to run ( `alert('hey')`) right inside `$scope.itemClick`-function?

Comment: alert('hey') is just an example - in reality I am going to show reveal modal.

I would like to open the modal on the html file where modal is defined.

Comment: so put that in the scope-function. Also like @Jinna Balu pointed out. Your scope function is not really valid javascript

Comment: as Gustav mentioned, you cannot access "not-angular-variables" in a parsed expression

Comment: @Mephiztopheles and Gustav got your point - but is it good idea to open up modal dialogs or other DOM related stuff inside controller function?

Comment: sure, there are services for this purpose. [angular ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for example has a `$modal`-service which you can use from your controller

Comment: [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog) call it dialog and have a service for it

Answer (score 0):

angular will replace `itemClick(cb)`
with kinda
`v1[...];var v0;if("cb" in s){v0 = s.cb} else if("cb" in l){v0 = l.cb} return v1(v0)`.

`s` is the scope and `l` is a object you can define when you want to pass variables into a function which you define in a directive: `{click:"&"}`
when you want to call the click-function, you do `$scope.click({$event:event})` and this object will be passed as `l`.
so your global created cb is not available in your scope.

Greetings